# Pushing and removeFromParentControllers, Affected the structure of navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtYVk.png)

Image on above link, cant include it in the post..
As I push from viewControllerA to B, then I push from B to C, then I use the following code to remove the viewControllerB and push C to B and remove viewControllerC:

```
    NSMutableArray *navigationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: self.navigationController.viewControllers];

    for(UIViewController *tempVC in navigationArray)
{
    if([tempVC isKindOfClass:[viewControllerB class]])
    {
        [tempVC removeFromParentViewController];
    }
}

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toViewControllerB" sender:self];

    for(UIViewController *tempVC in navigationArray)
    {
        if([tempVC isKindOfClass:[viewControllerC class]])
        {
            [tempVC removeFromParentViewController];
        }
    }
```

So now ViewControllerA is connected to the last ViewControllerB
After that I still get the back button in the navigation bar, but after I pressed the back button of it, the ViewControllerB popped back to ViewControllerA, but in the ViewControllerA, the navigation bar items and title are gone, I purposely push from C to B again to fix some memory issue, how can I make this work by taking out the two view controllers in the middle but not messing up the navigation controller? Is there any other alternatives to get this done? Thank you
I have another weird approach is to programatically create a navigation bar with the same items and title to cover it, but just seems so wrong...

Answer (score 0):

First when you want to push from B to C and then remove B, you can try this

```
for(UIViewController *tempVC in navigationArray)
{
    if([tempVC isKindOfClass:[viewControllerB class]])
    {
        [navigationArray removeObject:tempVC];
        break;
    }
}
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:navigationArray];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toViewControllerB" sender:self];
```

But you must ensure the `segue` is from C to B. Then you will get the Controllers A->C->B. If you want to push to ControllerC and remove Last C. Try to use the same function.

Answer (score 0):

1) When you first push to your C controller from B then first Remove B controller
2) When you push to B controller from C controller then remove C controller.

// Code for removing C Controller from stack

NSArray *viewControllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers;

```
NSMutableArray *viewControllersMutable = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:viewControllers];
for (UIViewController *vc in viewControllers) {
    if (([viewControllers indexOfObject:vc] != viewControllers.count - 1 ) && [vc isKindOfClass: C.class] ){
        NSLog(@"removing contoller of kind C");
        [viewControllersMutable removeObject:vc];
    }
}

self.navigationController.viewControllers = viewControllersMutable.copy;
```

// Code for removing B controller

NSArray *viewControllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers;

```
NSMutableArray *viewControllersMutable = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:viewControllers];
for (UIViewController *vc in viewControllers) {
    if (([viewControllers indexOfObject:vc] != viewControllers.count - 1 ) && [vc isKindOfClass: B.class] ){
        NSLog(@"removing contoller of kind B");
        [viewControllersMutable removeObject:vc];
    }
}

self.navigationController.viewControllers = viewControllersMutable.copy;
```

Note -> You can do this in a same code Only "OR" condition is checked, means the controller is B or C.